# copy ubuntu with my personalizations

Tags: installation, filesystem, system, personalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an install of Ubuntu to clone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21243/creating-an-install-of-ubuntu-to-clone)
>   [Reinstall software after installation of newer version Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25468/reinstall-software-after-installation-of-newer-version-ubuntu)

I have just installed ubuntu on my friends laptop. I will install ubuntu on my own machine next week, but I don't want to do that. I have not only installed ubuntu, but also installed a lot of applications and configure a lot of them (like Pidgin, Firefox, etc.). Is it possible to somehow copy the already installed ubuntu into a another machine?

Comment: @Christopher I don't agree with that duplicate. He wants to clone the current installation rather than upgrading is my understanding.

Comment: @gertvdijk Yes, the first link is much better. http://askubuntu.com/questions/21243/creating-an-install-of-ubuntu-to-clone